# How Google Maps Api Key can work in my html?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, http, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I created a site with google maps online (in javascript) .I took an api key from Google Maps, but it doesnt work, because every time i open the browser i receive an image with a message that it cann't load correctly the Google Mps. Do you know, should i have done something with HTTP referrer or with API libraries in Google Map Api's Settings??
[image]

[image]

Comment: are you sure you have a valid key setting in your html page  ..

Comment: Did you enable billing with a credit card?

Comment: the message  "for development porpouse only" appear when is not provided  a google maps apikey ..in googlemaps api call

Comment: yes my key is enable, i saw it in google maps settings.. and i call it in my js right. maybe the fault is that i don't insert an http referrer in google map's settings?? and what is that??

Comment: when you have obtained  the google maps key ? .. are you sure in you HTML page you have proper script section for google maps key  eg: `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=visualization">`

Answer (score 1):

Google's new billing and pricing model requires you to add a credit card to use even the free API's. The documentation/tutorial page which shows code examples, will provide a key, however it will not work until you add your billing info.

If you are using the Javascript API for Static Maps, it is no longer free but you can use the $200 monthly credit being offered. It should allow you over 1+ million maps loads per month.

https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/pricing/sheet/ https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial